# C# KrakenApi writing like "Invalid Key" but key is valid

Tags: c#, kraken.com

[enter image description here][1]Help to correct it please
C# KrakenApi writing like "Invalid Key" but key is valid. I just have no idea how to fix it, but I need it so much.

MAIN:
Create a URL for the Kraken Balance API

```
        var url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/private/Balance";
```

Create a request object

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
```

Add the API key header

```
        string apiKey = "API KEY";
        request.Headers.Add("API-Key", apiKey);
```

Add the secret key header

```
        string secret = "API SIGN";
        var nonce = GenerateNonce();
        var postData = $"nonce={nonce}";
        var apiSign = ComputeSignature(url, nonce, postData, secret);
        request.Headers.Add("API-Sign", apiSign);
```

Write the POST data to the request body

```
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
```

Get the response from the API

```
        try
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                // Read the response stream
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    // Convert the response to a string
                    var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    // Print the response
                    Console.WriteLine(responseString);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
```

If an error occurred, print the error message

```
            using (var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var error = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(error);
                }
            }
        }
```

methods:

```
    static string ComputeSignature(string url, string nonce, string postData, string secret)
    {
        var path = new Uri(url).AbsolutePath;
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nonce + postData);
        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512(Convert.FromBase64String(secret)))
        {
            var pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path);
            hmac.TransformBlock(pathBytes, 0, pathBytes.Length, pathBytes, 0);
            hmac.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            var hash = hmac.Hash;
            var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            return signature;
        }
    }

    static string GenerateNonce()
    {
        var nonce = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        return nonce.ToString();
    }
```

I tried get my balance in Kraken.com with API

tried some, but -, may be u can advice some from nuget packages

```
      public static byte[] ComputeSha256Hash(string nonce, string inputParams)
    {
        string combinedString = nonce + inputParams;
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(combinedString);

        using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(data);
            return hashBytes;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] ComputeSha512Hash(byte[] sha256Hash, string endpointName)
    {
        byte[] endpointBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(endpointName);
        byte[] combinedBytes = new byte[sha256Hash.Length + endpointBytes.Length];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(sha256Hash, 0, combinedBytes, 0, sha256Hash.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(endpointBytes, 0, combinedBytes, sha256Hash.Length, endpointBytes.Length);

        using (SHA512 sha512Hash = SHA512.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = sha512Hash.ComputeHash(combinedBytes);
            return hashBytes;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using Kraken.Net?

Comment: Nope, tried probably,but unsuccesfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my console application I have a `GetAccountBalance()` method. When I want to get my bitcoin balance, I am calling: `decimal volume = GetAccountBalance(asset: "BTC").Value;`.

**Broker.cs**

```
private decimal? GetAccountBalance(string asset)
{
    var response = GetAccountBalances();
    var balance = response["result"][asset]?.Value;
    var errors = response.error.ToObject<string[]>();
    Display.PrintErrors(errors);
    return decimal.Parse(balance);
}

public virtual dynamic GetAccountBalances()
{
    var json = KrakenApi.QueryPrivateEndpoint("Balance", null).Result;
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
    return response;
}
```

**KrakenApi.cs**

```
private const string BaseDomain = "https://api.kraken.com";
private const string PrivatePath = "/0/private/";
private static long LastUsedNonce;

public static async Task<string> QueryPrivateEndpoint(string endpointName, string inputParameters)
{           
    string apiEndpointFullURL = BaseDomain + PrivatePath + endpointName;
    string nonce = GetNextNonce();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputParameters) == false)
    {
        inputParameters = "&" + inputParameters;
    }
    string apiPostBodyData = "nonce=" + nonce + inputParameters;
    string signature = CreateAuthenticationSignature(endpointName, nonce, inputParameters);
    string jsonData;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("API-Key", ApiPublicKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("API-Sign", signature);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "KrakenDotNet Client");
        StringContent data = new StringContent(apiPostBodyData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiEndpointFullURL, data);
        jsonData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    Logger.AddEntry($"apiPostBodyData: {apiPostBodyData}");
    return jsonData;
}

public static string CreateAuthenticationSignature(string endpointName, string nonce, string inputParams)
{
    byte[] sha256Hash = ComputeSha256Hash(nonce, inputParams);
    byte[] sha512Hash = ComputeSha512Hash(sha256Hash, endpointName);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(sha512Hash);
}

private static string GetNextNonce()
{
    var nonce = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    if (nonce == LastUsedNonce) nonce += 1;
    LastUsedNonce = nonce;
    return nonce.ToString();
}

private static byte[] ComputeSha256Hash(string nonce, string inputParams)
{
    byte[] sha256Hash;
    string sha256HashData = nonce.ToString() + "nonce=" + nonce.ToString() + inputParams;
    using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
    {
        sha256Hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sha256HashData));
    }
    return sha256Hash;
}

private static byte[] ComputeSha512Hash(byte[] sha256Hash, string endpointName)
{
    string apiEndpointPath = PrivatePath + endpointName;
    byte[] apiEndpointPathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiEndpointPath);
    byte[] sha512HashData = apiEndpointPathBytes.Concat(sha256Hash).ToArray();
    HMACSHA512 encryptor = new HMACSHA512(Convert.FromBase64String(ApiPrivateKey));
    byte[] sha512Hash = encryptor.ComputeHash(sha512HashData);
    return sha512Hash;
}
```

I use a different nonce number every time. Check out [Kraken documentation](https://docs.kraken.com/rest/#section/Authentication/Nonce-and-2FA) for the details. Note `QueryPrivateEndpoint()` can also handle parameters in the query string. Finally you need to grant your api key with permission to retrieve your balance at the Kraken web site.

Comment: im so thank you, but maybe u can send me 

 GetNextNonce();  ComputeSha256Hash(nonce, inputParams); ComputeSha512Hash(sha256Hash, endpointName); functions

Comment: or just somewhere this your project?:/

Comment: Added the code I'm using to get the nonce. In theory it should be enough with `ToUnixTimeSeconds()` but I was getting "invalid nonce" error when adding orders too often.

Comment: im just getting this error: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'. I think it is cuz of ComputeSha256Hash; ComputeSha512Hash. may be i doing wrong

Comment: i am added, how i wrote these functions:/

Comment: IM LOVEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE YOUU BROOO it works